# Symfony: Autowiring does not work, debug:autowiring does not list own classes

Tags: php-7, autowired, symfony4

I am using Symfony 4.2

Here's my config for my classes i want to autowire:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
#        autoconfigure: true
    Cyrene\components\:
        resource: '../../app/components/*'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
        exclude:
            - '../../app/components/common/*'
```

The paths are correct, because using the `debug:container` command of symfony, it does show me all the classes i have in the "components"-folder.

But using the `debug:autowiring` command of symfony, it does not show any of my classes, even though they have the tag `controller.service_arguments`, which should make them autowireable.

**what i am doing wrong here?**

**I am facing another problem, too...**

although i am using one autowireable class, e.g., `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` (which is autowireable from symfony by default), symfony does not pass it to the constructor:

```
use Cyrene\core\actions\AbstractAdminAction;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class OverviewIndexAction extends AbstractAdminAction
{
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, OverviewIndexResponder $responder)
    {
        $this->responder = $responder;
    }
```

I get this error message: `[...] Too few arguments to function Cyrene\components\admin\application\overview\index\OverviewIndexAction::__construct(), 0 passed [...] but exactly 2 expected [...]`

that leads me to the assumption, that autowiring generally doesn't work.

the `$logger` should have been autowired, because it is listed with the `debug:autowiring` command of symfony. `OverviewIndexResponder $responder` is within the same path/namespace as `OverviewIndexAction`, hence no `use`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Symfony 4.2.0 - there is a bug in this version.

To fix that try:

```
composer require phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock
```

More about bug:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29442

Answer (score 0):

it's funny, oftenly you find the issue, when you ask someone else.

The issue was, that my own `ControllerResolver` did not extend the correct superclass.

This is correct:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver as SymfonyControllerResolver;

class ControllerResolver extends SymfonyControllerResolver
```

The `ContainerControllerResolver` takes care of injecting the correct objects.

although autowiring works, `debug:autowiring` still doesn't list my classes.